# reading files details into a string, and int

Tags: c, string, file, io, format

I have a file including (ID-9 digits, name-10 digits, quantity-4 digits) for example:

```
123456789 Dany Bany 1000
999999999 Bill 9
```

and I want to read these details:
ID to string, Name to string and number to int.

how can I do this? I should consider that there are names including 2 words and some of them including 1 word.
I try to use this but have a problem with 2 words name:

```
while (fscanf(file, "%s %s %d", id, name, &quantity) > 0) {
    printf("%s %s %d\n", id, name, quantity);
}
```

Comment: Read line, find first space from the beginning, find first space from the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file line by line, using [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).

For every line do:

1. Get the ID, by searching for the *first* space.
2. Get the number as a string, by searching for the *last* space.
   Convert it to an integer with [`atoi()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/).
3. The rest, unprocessed part of the line, is the Name.

---

Below is a naive and rushed implementation of this logic:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 100

int main(void)
{
    char line[LEN];
    FILE* fp = fopen("foo.txt", "r");
    while (1) {
        if (fgets(line, 100, fp) == NULL) break;
        printf("%s", line);
        char id[20];
        int j = 0;
        while(line[j] != ' ' && line[j] != '\0')
        {
            id[j] = line[j];
            j++;
        }
        id[j] = '\0';
        //printf("ID: %s\n", id);
        j++;
        size_t len = strlen(line);
        int i, end = 0, k = 0;
        char str_number[20];
        for(i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            if(line[i] == ' ')
            {
                end = i;
                ++i;
                while(i <= len)
                    str_number[k++] = line[i++];
                break;
            }
        }
        //printf("%s\n", str_number);
        int number = atoi(str_number);
        //printf("%d\n", number);
        char name[20];
        k = 0;
        for(i = j; i < end; ++i)
            name[k++] = line[i];
        name[k] = '\0';
        printf("ID: %s\n", id);
        printf("Number: %d\n", number);
        printf("Name: %s\n", name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
123456789 Dany Bany 1000
ID: 123456789
Number: 1000
Name: Dany Bany
999999999 Bill 9
ID: 999999999
Number: 9
Name: Bill
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to read the entire line into an array of characters using the `fgets()` function, then parsing the resulting string as you desire.

In parsing the resultant string, read the first characters before the first space and store that as a string for the ID. Then read the characters after the last space and convert to int. For this you will have to loop through the char array, while using the library functions in the `ctype` header file such as `isspace()`, `isdigit()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file line-by-line and use `split` to divide up the sections:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.array;
import std.conv;

void main() {
    auto f = File("/tmp/file.txt", "r");
    foreach (line ; f.byLine()) {
        auto parts = line.split();
        string id = parts[0].to!string;
        string name = parts[1..$-1].join(' ').to!string;
        int quantity = parts[$-1].to!int;

        writeln("id ", id, " name ", name, " quantity ", quantity);
    }
}
```

Comment: @gsamaras Did the OP want `c` or `d`? It was initially tagged `d`, and you edited it to `c`, but I didn't see any indication that it really was supposed to be C and not D.

Comment: rcorre and the person that upvoted your comment, please look into the edit history. The post was tagged by the OP as [tag:c]. Thank you.

Comment: @gsamaras the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44501991/1) was tagged `d`, then it was retagged to `c` during the [first edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44501991/2). I just realized that edit was not you, but it was also not the OP.

Comment: rcorre the OP meant to say C. d doesn't have `fscanf()`, I think. ;) However you are right, but I think he missed the right tag. Anyway. =)

Comment: D has access to the C std library, so it [does](http://dlang.org/phobos/core_stdc_stdio.html#.fscanf). It wouldn't be the recommended way to go about it though, which is why I suggested something different. Its a mystery what the original intent was, but I guess the OP has a variety of answers now :)